# Java - getOpenFileDescriptorCount for Windows

Tags: java, file-descriptor

How to get the number of open File descriptors under Windows?

On unix there is this:

```
UnixOperatingSystemMXBean.getOpenFileDescriptorCount()
```

But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for windows?

Answer (score 1):

This was going to be a comment but got a little long winded.

Conflicting answers as to why there may be a lack of equivalence [here on ServerFault: Windows Server 2008 R2 max open files limit](https://serverfault.com/a/249498/397675). TLDR: Windows is only limited by available hardware vs Windows is limited by 32 vs 64 bit implementation ([MS Technet Blog Post - Pushing the Limits of Windows: Handles](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/09/29/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-handles/)). Granted, this is old information.

But! if you note the JavaDocs for the `com.sun.management` [package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/index.html?com/sun/management/UnixOperatingSystemMXBean.html), you will of course note the conspicuous absence of a Windows version of the the `UnixOperatingSystemMXBean` that would extend [OperatingSystemMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) to provide the functionality. Even `UnixOperatingSystemMXBean` only exists to provide `getMaxFileDescriptorCount()` and `getOpenFileDescriptorCount()` so it seems unlikely that Windows has the same concept.

Edit:

I did find a nice little program that sort of shows this off, which I tweaked.
[Descriptors.java](https://gist.github.com/jtai/5408684)

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Descriptors {
    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        System.out.println(osMxBean.getClass().getName());
        OperatingSystemMXBean osMxBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
        try {
            Method getMaxFileDescriptorCountField = osMxBean.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getMaxFileDescriptorCount");
            Method getOpenFileDescriptorCountField = osMxBean.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getOpenFileDescriptorCount");
            getMaxFileDescriptorCountField.setAccessible(true);
            getOpenFileDescriptorCountField.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println(getOpenFileDescriptorCountField.invoke(osMxBean) + "/" + getMaxFileDescriptorCountField.invoke(osMxBean));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On Linux:

```
com.sun.management.UnixOperatingSystem
11/2048
```

On Windows:

```
sun.management.OperatingSystemImpl
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
sun.management.OperatingSystemImpl.getMaxFileDescriptorCount()
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
at Descriptors.main(Descriptors.java:10)
```